# How Pass Referenced DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, parameter-passing, ref

I Work on C# Project

I Have 2 Classes Like this:

```
public class A
{
    public DataTable dtA {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    DataTable dtB{get;set;}

    public B(DataTable dt)
    {
        dtB = dt;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B(a.dtA);
}
```

I Want that dtB Be Exactly dtA (ref dtA). But with Up Code dtB is New DataTable, And is Not dtA.
(i Want When Change dtB , this Change apply on dtA too)

How Solve My Problem?

---

**SOLVED:**

if dtA Was null and Pass to dtB, dtB Always Will null.(even When dtA fill with Data)
But if dtA was not null and pass to dtB, dtB and dtA Will from One Source.

Comment: compound types are passed by reference automatically, your code is fine

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as you intend because DataTable is a reference type. 
However you need to pay attention because you can easily fall in this situation

```
void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.dtA = new DataTable("TestTable");
    B b = new B(a.dtA);
    Console.WriteLine(b.TableName); // Same as A.dtA
    Console.WriteLine(a.dtA.TableName);  // Same as internal datatable in B
    a.dtA = new DataTable("SecondTable");
    Console.WriteLine(b.TableName);   // No more the same as A.dtA
    Console.WriteLine(a.dtA.TableName);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class A
{
    public DataTable dtA;
}

public class B
{
    DataTable dtB{get;set;}

    public B(DataTable dt)
    {
        dtB = dt;
    }
    public string TableName
    {
        get{ return dtB.TableName;}
        set{ dtB.TableName = value;}
    }
}
```

As you can see, changing the DataTable in A will leave the DataTable in B still pointing to the old reference and thus the two are no more the same. Check the answer from Tim Schmelter for a better approach.

Comment: Hi, I am unable to understand that since DataTable is a class and its object dt, is acting as value type. FillDataTable(myDt); , whenever i use this method, I have to return DataTable; or if i don't myDt remains blank. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

try with ref

```
public B(ref DataTable dt)
{
    dtB = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `A` and `B` point to the same `DataTable`, that is because all reference types (as `DataTable`) are passed by reference so your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same `DataTable` you should use the same reference of `A`:

```
public class A
{
    public DataTable dtA;
}

public class B
{
    public A a;

    public B(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Now both are using the same table:

```
static void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B(a);
    Console.Write(a.dtA == b.A.dtA); //true
}
```

You could also let `B` inherit from `A` if that is what you actually want:

```
public class B: A
{      
}

static void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    Console.Write(a.dtA == b.dtA); //true
}
```